# What does the number of maximum containers per node mean in Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

In Hadoop MapReduce Tutorial, I saw the words

> The right number of reduces seems to be 0.95 or 1.75 multiplied by (< no. of nodes > * **< no. of maximum containers per node >**).

But I don’t know what **no. of maximum containers per node**  is and how to set it. And I want to know how to set the number of reducers per node. I haven’t get any clues in docments yet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247059/why-is-the-right-number-of-reduces-in-hadoop-0-95-or-1-75 this link has the answer you are looking for

Comment: sorry, the appearance of original question was wrong. I re-edited it.

Answer (score 0):

A YARN NodeManager is started with a maximum JVM size

A YARN container has its own, configurable size.

Divide your smallest NodeManager by the YARN Container size for a job, and this will be the max containers for a node